# IIS redirect subfolder to subdomain

Tags: redirect, iis

I am trying to create a Rewrite Rule to redirect https://www.example.com/blog to https://blog.example.com

Here is the rule as it appears in my web.config file:

```
<rule name="blog redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^blog(.*?)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I have a similar rule which works as expected:

```
<rule name="Redirect MOB to FULL" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*?)foo/bar(.*?)MOB(.*?)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}foo/bar{R:2}FULL{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

I've tried using `(.*?)blog(.*?)$` instead of `^blog(.*?)$` in case there was something wrong with my regex, but it doesn't make a difference.

Do I need to do something special to redirect to a subdomain or external URL?

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in your rule do not match, If you want redirect https://www.example.com/blog to https://blog.example.com, you can refer to this rule:

```
<rule name="subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^blog/(.*)|blog" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If your URL is dynamic, please specify your needs.

Comment: The URL is dynamic. I want to capture everything that comes after blog and add it to the end of the new URL.

https://www.example.com/blog/foo/bar.php should redirect to https://blog.example.com/foo/bar.php

Comment: I modified my rule, hope this will help you.